# Updating a table in DynamoDb using FilterExpression

Tags: amazon-dynamodb, aws-sdk-nodejs

So I have this JSON object

```
{
  "id": "c66c588e",
  "players": {
    "M2cfydGooAMCLpQ=": {},
    "ygjjgy7678": {}
  }
}
```

For a given player Id, I want to update that particular object, so it becomes

```
{
  "id": "c66c588e",
  "players": {
    "M2cfydGooAMCLpQ=": {
      "cards": [
        {
          "cardId": "id1",
          "cardTitle": "title here"
        }
      ]
    },
    "ygjjgy7678": {}
  }
}
```

This is the query I have

```
const params = {
    TableName: process.env.DYNAMODB_GAMES_TABLE, 
    Key: {
        id: gameId
    },
    UpdateExpression: 'set players.#player = list_append(if_not_exists(#cards, :empty_list), :card)',
    ExpressionAttributeNames: {
      '#cards': 'cards',
      '#player': playerId
    },
    ExpressionAttributeValues: {
      ':card': [{
        "cardId": cardId,
        "cardTitle": cardTitle,
        "pun": pun
      }],
      ':empty_list': []
    },
    ReturnValues: "ALL_NEW"
  };
```

But I get this error

```
{
  "message": "The document path provided in the update expression is invalid for update",
  "code": "ValidationException",
  "time": "2020-05-21T00:50:32.236Z",
  "requestId": "HLJJA2QQ2POAQEAJUD3143T6PJVV4KQNSO5AEMVJF66Q9ASUAAJG",
  "statusCode": 400,
  "retryable": false,
  "retryDelay": 38.70011614235671
}
```

I cannot seem to figure out how to update a particular player. 
I think creating a new Index will result in additional AWS costs which I want to avoid.

Comment: `FilterExpression` is used when to filter the returned results of a query operation. You're performing an update operation.

Comment: got it. So I am looking for an update expression where the attribute key is random

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out.

The key should be a valid key which you can access by obj.key and not obj[key]

Then this query will work

```
const params = {
    TableName: process.env.DYNAMODB_GAMES_TABLE, 
    Key: {
        id: gameId
    },
    UpdateExpression: 'set players.#player = list_append(if_not_exists(#cards, :empty_list), :card)',
    ExpressionAttributeNames: {
      '#cards': 'cards',
      '#player': playerId
    },
    ExpressionAttributeValues: {
      ':card': [{
        "cardId": cardId,
        "cardTitle": cardTitle,
        "pun": pun
      }],
      ':empty_list': []
    },
    ReturnValues: "ALL_NEW"
  };
```